# Pthreads and kthreads

Tags: android, linux, pthreads, kernel, semaphore

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement kernel threads for a producer consumer scenario? Also if someone could show me how to use kernel's doubly linked list (bounded buffer) in the implementation of this example.

I so far understand how to initialize and use the pthreads, and mutexes for the synchronization of the program, but I cant seem to figure out how to do it with kernel threads.

The prog lang. im using is C

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? What are your goals, how far did you get, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conceptual part, you can read Robert Love's [Linux Kernel Development](http://www.amazon.ca/Linux-Kernel-Development-3rd-Edition/dp/0672329468). The book generally says you can use functions like

```
struct task_struct * kthread_create (...);
```

`struct task_struct * kthread_run (...);`

```
struct task_struct * kthread_stop (...);
```

to manage threads. Threads are actually light-weight processes in the kernel. So you would need to do your homework on processes as well, if you haven't done so.

For the consumer-producer problem, here's an example [using pthread](http://cis.poly.edu/cs3224a/Code/ProducerConsumerUsingPthreads.c).

Hope this helps.